# How to pass (new FormData(this)) with another parameter but i didn't get in upload.php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

Below is my Code JS code, i want to pass comment parameter to ajax with FormData. Kindly help me to get this one. I have tried to create my_object and added form object and comment hi, but i am not able to get data in upload.php.

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $("#uploadForm").on('submit',(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var myData = new FormData(this);
        console.log(myData);
        //var formObj=new FormData(this);
        //var my_object = {"form": formObj, "comment":"hi"};
        $.ajax({
            url: "upload.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: new FormData(this),
            //data:my_object,
            contentType: false,
            cache: false,
            processData:false,
            success: function(data)
            {
            $("#targetLayer").html(data);
            },
            error: function() 
            {
            }           
       });
    }));
});
```

**I want to pass the comment parameter?**
Below is my PHP code. upload.php

```
if(is_array($_FILES)) {
if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'])) {
$sourcePath = $_FILES['userImage']['tmp_name'];
$targetPath = "images/".$_FILES['userImage']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($sourcePath,$targetPath)) {
    print_r($_FILES);
?>
<img class="image-preview" width="60" height="80" src="<?php echo $targetPath; ?>" class="upload-preview" />
<?php
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [set](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/set) function of the FormData class

```
myData.set('commment', 'value');
```